# Minimizing number of Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have this:

```
data = []

products.each do |product|
  categories = product.shop_categories.select("shop_categories.id, shop_categories.name").map do |category|
  {
    :name => category.name,
    :category_id => category.id.to_s
  }
  end

  data << {
   :name => product.name,
   :product_id => product.productid,
   :manufacturer => product.manufacturer,
   :detail => product.description,
   :categories => categories,
   :sales_rank => product.sales_rank,
   :sale_price => product.sale_price.to_f,
   :price => product.price.to_f,
   :images => product.images,
   :url => product.url,
   :is_rated => current_user.voted_for?(product),
   :is_liked => current_user.voted_as_when_voted(product),
   :is_in_wishlist => current_user.has_product_in_wishlist?(product)
  }
end
```

This part where products are searched for its `shop_categories` are taking up a huge amount of time to query since every product (100 per run) when it searches for the products' `shop_categories`.

Is there a way to minimize the number of queries or at least minimize the CPU being used up by this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`includes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) to eager-load the association:

```
data = Product.includes(:shop_categories).collect do |product|
  {
    :name => product.name,
    :product_id => product.productid,
    :manufacturer => product.manufacturer,
    :detail => product.description,
    :categories => product.categories.collect { |c| { :name => c.name, :category_id => c.id.to_s } },
    :sales_rank => product.sales_rank,
    :sale_price => product.sale_price.to_f,
    :price => product.price.to_f,
    :images => product.images,
    :url => product.url,
    :is_rated => current_user.voted_for?(product),
    :is_liked => current_user.voted_as_when_voted(product),
    :is_in_wishlist => current_user.has_product_in_wishlist?(product)
  }
end
```

Comment: Using `include` still require you to do the queries (1+N).